# How to select records not on log table using Laravel 4 Eloquent hasMany relation?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-4

My table schema

```
+rules 
 -id
 -title
 -description

+log
 -id
 -rules_id
 -date  MYSQL(YYYY-mm-dd)
```

I execute rules daily and update on logs table. How do I fetch rules that did not execute today?

Rule module

```
public function log()
{
    return $this->hasMany('Log');
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `whereDoesntHave`:

```
$rules = Rules::whereDoesntHave('log', function($q){
    $q->where('date', Carbon::now()->toDateString());
})->get();
```

`whereDoesntHave` has only been added recently (Dec 2014) You might have to update Laravel. If you can't use this:

```
$rules = Rules::whereHas('log', function($q){
    $q->where('date', Carbon::now()->toDateString());
}, '<', 1)->get();
```

Comment: what is Carbon::now ?

Comment: [Carbon](https://github.com/briannesbitt/Carbon) is a datetime library Laravel uses. And `Carbon::now()` (Sorry not `Carbon::now`) returns... well *now*, the current date

Comment: It worked! .. I'm using YYYY-mm-dd on mysql, Carbon::now() returns date with time after removing it, the code worked!

Answer (score 0):

you can use simple query without eloquent if you don't know much about Carbon::now() mention by @lukasgeiter

```
$today = DATE('Y-m-d');
$rules = DB::table('rules')
        ->select('rules.id','rules.title','rules.description','log.date')
        ->join('log', 'rules.id', '=', 'rules.rules_id')
        ->where('DATE(log.date)', '!=', $today)
        ->first();
```

Comment: This only changes the eager loaded logs but doesn't filter the actual rules returned.

Comment: yes you are right @lukasgeiter changed query. thanks for knowlegde share about Carbon::now()